# EnterpriseLibrary.Logging severity level setting in app.config

Tags: app-config, enterprise-library, event-log

I'm maintaining a windows service that is written a long time ago and the first author has left the company way before I joint.

I want to reduce the eventlog records by leveling up the severity from `Information` to `Warning`. But when I check the setting in app.config, I can't find any field that seems to be able to limit severity to write.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="CompanyName0PBR_Service.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     source="PBRProcessing" formatter="Text Formatter" log="CompanyName0PKPBR_Service" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Message: {message}{newline}" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="Off" name="All Events"/>
      <notProcessed switchValue="Off" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
      <errors switchValue="Off" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

And the related topic is surprisingly difficult to find on the internet.
Is anyone still using this solution could guide me where to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

It's in `switchValue`.

The usage is like `<add switchValue="Warning"` will log severity >= Warning.